# Add title from json to text Content in html

Tags: javascript

I have to add all titles from my `data` in js, to each `textContent` in `<h3 class="title"></h3>`

I'm stuck:( Here is my code :

```
<div class="info-container">
   <h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>
<div class="info-container">
   <h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>
<div class="info-container">
   <h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const data = [
  {
    "title": "ASD"
  },
  {
    "title": "FGH"
  }
]
const list_title = document.querySelectorAll('.title')

data.map(item => {
  console.log(item.title)

  //I want to add item.title to textContent of each list_title, to show each title in HTML
})
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KF52qHjh8e6ubTCS2545?p=preview

Thanks for answers in advance!

Answer (score 3):

> `map()` utilizes return values and actually returns a new Array of the same size.
>
> The `forEach()` method doesn't actually return anything (`undefined`). It simply calls a provided function on each element in the array.

[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is better fit here to set the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) property of the element by matcing the *index*.

The *index* is optional and can be passed as the second parameter as the *index* of the current element being processed in the array.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "title": "ASD"
  },
  {
    "title": "FGH"
  }
]
const list_title = document.querySelectorAll('.title')

data.forEach( (item, idx) => {
  console.log(item.title)
  list_title[idx].textContent = item.title;
})
```

```html
<div class="info-container">
   <h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>
<div class="info-container">
   <h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>
<div class="info-container">
   <h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `map()`. You should use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). `forEach()` accepts a callback in second parameter is index of element.So you can set `textContent` of element at that index in `list_title`

```
data.forEach((item,i) => {
  list_title[i].textContent = item.title
})
```

Here is working snippet.

```js
const data = [{"title": "ASD"},{"title": "FGH"}]
const list_title = document.querySelectorAll('.title')

data.forEach((item,i) => {
      list_title[i].textContent = item.title
})
```

```html
<div class="info-container">
   <h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>
<div class="info-container">
   <h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>
<div class="info-container">
   <h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the previously used `setAttribute()`?.....Now the answer is identical to my one!

Comment: @Mamun Actually I misread the question. I thought that he is asking for setting title attribute. But I came to knew that he want to add `textContent` so I updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think making this change in you data.map function is suffice to achieve the result you want.

```
data.map((item, index) => {
  console.log(list_title)
  list_title[index].innerText = item.title
  //I want to add item.title to textContent of each list_title, to show each title in HTML
})
```

If you don't know how many list of books will be there you may want to make these changes:
In index.html:

```
<body>
  <div id="info-container">

   </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

In app.js:

```
const info_container = document.getElementById('info-container')

data.forEach((item, index) => {
  const title = document.createElement("h3");
  const node = document.createTextNode(item.title);
  title.appendChild(node);

  // appending h3 with title in inside the container.
  info_container.appendChild(title);

})
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding :)